# Creditcard regex is not working in flutter

Tags: regex, flutter, dart, credit-card

I am trying to determine which credit card is it? and render Image Widget accordingly. but somehow its not working, I don't know If I miss something or is my approach is wrong

Here's the code snippet

Its always render the last else part.

[image: Input image]

Input Suffix Icon part where I am rendering container based on number

```
VxState.watch(context, on: [HandleInputChanges]);
TextField(
     maxLength: 16,
     decoration: InputDecoration(
          counter: const Offstage(),
          suffixIcon: getCreditCardType(store.moniPay.cardNo) // Here I am rendering image,
     hintText: "Input card number",
     onChanged: (String? value) {
          HandleInputChanges(value.toString(), 'cardno');
      })
```

And here's the getCreditCardType method

```
Widget getCreditCardType(String creditCardNumber) {
  if (RegExp(r"^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$").hasMatch(creditCardNumber)) {
    // visa card
    return Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage("assets/images/visa.png"),
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
      ),
    ));
  } else if (RegExp(r"^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$").hasMatch(creditCardNumber)) {
    // master card
    return Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage("assets/images/master.png"),
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
      ),
    ));
  } else if (RegExp(r"^3[47][0-9]{13}$").hasMatch(creditCardNumber)) {
    // AExpress card
    return Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage("assets/images/american-express.png"),
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
      ),
    ));
  } else if (RegExp(r"^3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}$")
      .hasMatch(creditCardNumber)) {
    // diner card
    return Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage("assets/images/dinners-club.png"),
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
      ),
    ));
  } else if (RegExp(r"^6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}$")
      .hasMatch(creditCardNumber)) {
    // discover card
    return Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage("assets/images/discover.png"),
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
      ),
    ));
  } else if (RegExp(r"^(?:2131|1800|35\\d{3})\\d{11}$")
      .hasMatch(creditCardNumber)) {
    // JCB card
    return Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage("assets/images/jcb.png"),
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
      ),
    ));
  } else {
    return const Icon(Icons.credit_card);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you need "live input validation"? Try replacing the first regex (`RegExp(r"^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$")`) with `^4[0-9]{0,15}$`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, I need live input validation, and thank you that work for visa card, any idea about master card and JCB card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For live validation, you need to make sure that each subsequent digit can only be entered if the current substring is valid.

You can use

```
^5(?:[1-5][0-9]{0,14})?$                   # VISA
^5(?:[1-5][0-9]{0,14})?$                   # MASTER CARD
^3(?:[47][0-9]{0,13})?$                    # AEXPRESS CARD
^3(?:(?:0[0-5]?|[68][0-9]?)[0-9]{0,11})?$  # DINER CARD
^6(?:(?:01{0,2}|5[0-9]{0,2})[0-9]{0,12})?$ # DISCOVER CARD
```

The updated code will look like:

```js
Widget getCreditCardType(String creditCardNumber) {
  if (RegExp(r"^4[0-9]{0,15}$").hasMatch(creditCardNumber)) {
    // visa card
    return Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage("assets/images/visa.png"),
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
      ),
    ));
  } else if (RegExp(r"^5(?:[1-5][0-9]{0,14})?$").hasMatch(creditCardNumber)) {
    // master card
    return Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage("assets/images/master.png"),
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
      ),
    ));
  } else if (RegExp(r"^3(?:[47][0-9]{0,13})?$").hasMatch(creditCardNumber)) {
    // AExpress card
    return Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage("assets/images/american-express.png"),
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
      ),
    ));
  } else if (RegExp(r"^3(?:(?:0[0-5]?|[68][0-9]?)[0-9]{0,11})?$")
      .hasMatch(creditCardNumber)) {
    // diner card
    return Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage("assets/images/dinners-club.png"),
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
      ),
    ));
  } else if (RegExp(r"^6(?:(?:01{0,2}|5[0-9]{0,2})[0-9]{0,12})?$")
      .hasMatch(creditCardNumber)) {
    // discover card
    return Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage("assets/images/discover.png"),
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
      ),
    ));
  } else if (RegExp(r"^(?:2(?:1(?:31?)?)?|1(?:80{0,2})?|3(?:5\d{0,3})?)\d{0,11}$")
      .hasMatch(creditCardNumber)) {
    // JCB card
    return Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage("assets/images/jcb.png"),
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
      ),
    ));
  } else {
    return const Icon(Icons.credit_card);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've tried the function you wrote down, and it appears that the regex pattern only recognize the full/complete format of the credit card. So it is a "validation regex" instead of "classification regex".

[image: Complete Visa number recognized]
[image: Complete AE number recognized]

It doesn't recognize incomplete credit card numbers, so it will always return the last else part.

[image: Incomplete Visa number not recognized]

Comment: Thanks, now I realise what is the issue, any idea how we can achive live validation here instead of writing full number